# How to efficiently stream an object graph as xml to sql server

Tags: c#, sql, xml-serialization

I have an object graph that I need to serialize to xml and save to a Sql Server row. I have a table with an xml data type and I've been using the SqlXml datatype, providing it a memorystream.

This works well for the most part. However, if my object graph is especially big (~200 meg in size), I get an OutOfMemoryException. What is the most efficient way to serialize an object graph as xml and stream it to Sql Server? Here is my code right now:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.Settings.GetConnectionString()))
    {
    connection.Open();

    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();

    command.CommandText = "INSERT_MESSAGE";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    SqlParameter param = command.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@PARTITION_ID";
    param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
    param.Value = this.PartitionId;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = command.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@MESSAGE";
    param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Xml;

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageContext));
    xs.Serialize(ms, message);
    param.Value = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlXml(ms);

    command.Parameters.Add(param);

    param = command.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@RETURN_VALUE";
    param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
    command.Parameters.Add(param);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if ((int)command.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value == 1)
        throw new IntegrationSystemException("Unknown error encountered while selecting the record count");
    else
    {
        if (log.IsInfoEnabled)
        log.InfoFormat("Saved message [{0}]", message.MessageId);
    }
    }
}
```

I am considering using a "hybridstream" like found here: [HybridStream](http://www.danielahill.com/post/Using-a-Hybrid-Memory-Stream-to-reduce-RAM-requirements.aspx). This basically allocates a MemoryStream to some arbitrary limit, when that limit is hit, it creates a FileStream for the surplus.

Optimization help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a large object graph, try first serializing to a file on disk, then passing the FileStream to SqlXmL.

Comment: I'll go with the HybridStream approach - I think that it provides the best of both worlds - high perf memory stream for small files (90% of all transactions) but safety of a FileStream for those big ones.